# Get info on multiple GitHub repos given list of owner/repo names

Tags: github, batch-processing, github-api, rate-limiting

There is the below API endpoint which returns info on a single repo given owner/repo names:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get

`GET /repos/:owner/:repo`

Is there a way to batch-get info on multiple repos given multiple pairs of owner/repo names, without having to make a ton of requests?

There's the `search` endpoint which returns info on 100 repos at once, so seems like GitHub would allow this to a reasonable limit.

https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to batch-get info on multiple repos given multiple pairs of owner/repo names, without having to make a ton of requests?

Apr. 2023, yes there is with the [GitHub CLI `gh` 2.28.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.28.0) and [`gh search repos`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_search_repos)

The `--owner` flag can now take multiple values as well as CSV values.

```
gh search repos --owner user1 --owner user2 --owner user3,user4
```

That would show all repositories by user1, user2, user3 and user4.

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't any way to do this. You have to make one request per repository.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I'll just keep keep hammering the server with multiple http `GET`s then.

Comment: This answer is obsolete and not correct anymore. There are multiple way with CLI and graphQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the GitHub GraphQL API:

PRO: get only what you need without any clutter by specifying only the fields you need.

CON: You need to get the GraphQL node ids first, which is a bit complicated and still requires multiple calls.

Get the repository ID like this:

```
{
  repository(owner: "github", name: "gitignore") {
    databaseId 
    id
    name
    nameWithOwner
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "repository": {
            "databaseId": 1062897,
            "id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMDYyODk3",
            "name": "gitignore",
            "nameWithOwner": "github/gitignore"
        }
    }
}
```

- get "owner" + "name" directly from the GitHub URL in your browser: https://github.com/github/gitignore
- `databaseId` is the integer id field you also get from the REST API
- `id` is a base64 encoded representation of the `databaseId`
- find all possible fields in the [GraphQL docs](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#repository)

If you decode `MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMDYyODk3` with base64 you get `010:Repository1062897`. You can read more what this means in this [github community discussion](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/39777).

#### Now you can get multiple repositories in a single call:

You need to use [global node IDs (GraphQL docs)](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/guides/using-global-node-ids):

```
{
  nodes(ids: ["MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMDYyODk3", "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnk3NjkxNjMx"]) {
    ... on Repository {
      databaseId
      nameWithOwner
      createdAt
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "data": {
        "nodes": [
            {
                "databaseId": 7691631,
                "nameWithOwner": "moby/moby",
                "createdAt": "2013-01-18T18:10:57Z"
            },
            {
                "databaseId": 1062897,
                "nameWithOwner": "github/gitignore",
                "createdAt": "2010-11-08T20:17:14Z"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the databaseIds don't work on `nodes`.