# Get info about several repositories from Github Graphql API in a single call

Tags: github, graphql, github-graphql

I am trying to create a query to Github GraphQL API that receive a list of repos as a parameter, and returns the info of those repositories in a single API call, does anyone know how to do that?

Something like this (I know this doesn't work)

```
query myOrgRepos($repos: [String!]!) {
  search(query:"""
  repo in $repos
  """, type: REPOSITORY, first: 100) {
      repo: nodes {
          ... on Repository{
              name
              description
              updatedAt
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: I think that the right way would be query:"repo:org/repo1 repo:org/repo2 repo:org/repo3"

Comment: See also [`gh search repo --owner user1,user2,...`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76139450/6309) as an alternative to GraphQL query.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding of your question is that you want to input a list of "known" repos and output information about them. In this case you can form a query of the following type.

```
{
  nodes(ids: ["node_id_1", "node_id_2"]) {
    ... on Repository {
      nameWithOwner
      createdAt
    }
  }
}
```

Here the `ids` are the `node_ids` of the repositories you are interested in. You can obtain these by individual GraphQL calls as follows

```
{
  repository(owner: "owner", name: "name") {
    id
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@David Butler gave an excellent answer on using GitHub's GraphQL API.

I will extend the answer by giving more context:

Get the repository ID like this:

```
{
  repository(owner: "github", name: "gitignore") {
    databaseId 
    id
    name
    nameWithOwner
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "repository": {
            "databaseId": 1062897,
            "id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMDYyODk3",
            "name": "gitignore",
            "nameWithOwner": "github/gitignore"
        }
    }
}
```

- get "owner" + "name" directly from the GitHub URL in your browser: https://github.com/github/gitignore
- `databaseId` is the integer id field you also get from the REST API
- `id` is a base64 encoded representation of the `databaseId`
- find all possible fields in the [GraphQL docs](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#repository)

If you decode `MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMDYyODk3` with base64 you get `010:Repository1062897`. You can read more what this means in this [github community discussion](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/39777).

#### Now you can get multiple repositories in a single call:

You need to use [global node IDs (GraphQL docs)](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/guides/using-global-node-ids):

```
{
  nodes(ids: ["MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMDYyODk3", "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnk3NjkxNjMx"]) {
    ... on Repository {
      databaseId
      nameWithOwner
      createdAt
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "data": {
        "nodes": [
            {
                "databaseId": 7691631,
                "nameWithOwner": "moby/moby",
                "createdAt": "2013-01-18T18:10:57Z"
            },
            {
                "databaseId": 1062897,
                "nameWithOwner": "github/gitignore",
                "createdAt": "2010-11-08T20:17:14Z"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the databaseIds don't work on `nodes`.

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to understand your comment so I will post the answer in full. The key is to use Github's advanced search “syntax” in the query string,  see [here](https://github.com/search/advanced) for examples.

The following query will find all repositories of user “github” as well as the graphql-js repository of user “graphql”:

```graphql
query {
  search(query: "user:github repo:graphql/graphql-js" type: REPOSITORY first: 10) {
    nodes {
      ... on Repository {
        name
        description
        updatedAt
      }
    }
  }
}
```